# Setting hh:mm to 24 hours format in one single t-sql Query - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I got a query which returns some hh:ss time values. The problem however is that it returns it in  a PM/AM format while it needs to be a 24 hours format. I can't change the global language setting because this 24 hours time setting is query specific.

I was wondering how to solve this issue? 
The query I got now is as follows:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Datum, dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Relatie, 
    dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.[Order], dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Status, 
    dbo.WorkOrder.DeviceID, dbo.Relaties.RelatieNaam AS Monteur, 
    dbo.Orders.Omschrijving AS OrderOmschrijving, 
    Format(dbo.WorkOrder.WBTravelDeparture, 'hh:mm') AS TravelDeparture, 
    Format(dbo.WorkOrder.WBTravelArrival, 'hh:mm') AS TravelArrival, 
    Format(dbo.WorkOrder.WBWorkArrival, 'hh:mm') AS WorkArrival, 
    Format(dbo.WorkOrder.WBWorkDeparture, 'hh:mm') AS WorkDeparture, 
    (CASE WHEN WorkOrder.[WBtravelhours] IS NULL 
            THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(WorkOrder.[WBTravelHours] * 100.0 / 100.0 AS DECIMAL(30, 2))) END) AS TravelHours, 
    (CASE WHEN WorkOrder.[wbworkhours] IS NULL 
            THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(WorkOrder.[WBWorkHours] * 100.0 / 100.0 AS DECIMAL(30, 2))) END) AS WorkHours, 
    dbo.qryWBMontageGeboekt.Geboekt, dbo.Orders.OpdAdres, 
    dbo.Orders.OpdPC, dbo.Orders.OpdPlaats, 
    LEFT(dbo.Orders.Omschrijving, 9) AS Expr1
FROM            
    dbo.qryWBMontageGeboekt 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Orders 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Relaties 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.WorkOrder 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.qryMPDisplayPre ON dbo.WorkOrder.WONummer = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.[Order] 
                        AND dbo.WorkOrder.WOStatus = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Status 
                        AND dbo.WorkOrder.WOAssignmentDate = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Datum 
    ON dbo.Relaties.RelatieNummer = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Relatie 
    ON dbo.Orders.Nummer = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.[Order] 
    ON dbo.qryWBMontageGeboekt.Datum = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Datum 
       AND dbo.qryWBMontageGeboekt.Relatie = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Relatie 
       AND dbo.qryWBMontageGeboekt.[Order] = dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.[Order]
WHERE        
    (dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Datum > '11/1/2012') 
    AND (dbo.qryMPDisplayPre.Status <> 0)
```

It is kinda weird since the values in `WorkArrival` are getting displayed correctly in the 24-hours format. Though the values in `TravelDeparture`, `TravelArrival` and `WorkDeparture` aren't while they are formatted the same way as the `WorkArrival` one.

So this made me believe that there was something wrong with the values from where they are fetched, the `WorkOrder` table. Though this table contains date times in a 24-hours way and they are all the same (so this couldn't be the problem).

See here the `workorder` table from where the values are fetched:

[image]

As you can see this are all dates with 24 hour HH:MM values.

Now below you can see the Query results with its PM/AM formatted time values:

[image]

As you can see the Query results are very weird. It seems that the `WorkArrival` fields returns its value correct, but the others don't. What is also strange is the fact that the field `TravelDeparture` returns some off its values correctly (2 top ones) but others incorrect..

Any clue how this can happen, and how I can let the values return in a 24 hours manor (in the query results).

Comment: Did a fix using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),dbo.WorkOrder.WBTravelArrival,108)` which gets the right results. Though still wondering why in one field it gets the right values and in the other not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example they should all be in 12 hour format, and I see no reason for it not being the case. The format for 12 hours is 'hh' and you are using it in all places.

Is this your original query? If not then check your format strings for upper / lower case. The format for 24 hours happens to be 'HH' (upper case instead of lower case being the only difference).

Comment: Yep it is the original query so no clue why it does the incorrect formatting in some places. Thank you for the info about using HH. I didn't knew that! I changed all the hh lower cases to upper cases and now it results the correct times!